# Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods | Seasonal_Decompose

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, data-analysis, decomposition

I have a temp DF that has the following data in it

```
Quarter
2016Q3    146660510.0
2016Q4    123641451.0
2017Q1    125905843.0
2017Q2    129656327.0
2017Q3    126586708.0
2017Q4    116804168.0
2018Q1    118167263.0
2018Q2    121633740.0
2018Q3    125314447.0
2018Q4    120994896.0
2019Q1    126124709.0
2019Q2    134753318.0
```

I'm passing this into [seasonal_decompose](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html?highlight=seasonal_decompose#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose) as quarterly data as per below but I get an error messsage saying "Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods". Frequency has been set in the DF. I think the issue is related to the fact you have to specify to matplotlib that the x axis is periods but I don't know how to do that and can't find any other examples where a [DecomposeResult](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.DecomposeResult.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.DecomposeResult) object with quarters is used

```
result = seasonal_decompose(temp, model='additive',period=4)  
result.plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Just convert your PeriodIndex to a DatetimeIndex, that will solve the issue:

```
    df.index = df.index.to_timestamp()
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but not really an answer. According to the documentation of seasonal_compose this should work as in the code of the OP, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 date=['2016Q3'
 ,'2016Q4'
 ,'2017Q1'
 ,'2017Q1'
 ,'2017Q3'
 ,'2017Q4'
 ,'2018Q1'
 ,'2018Q3'
 ,'2018Q3'
 ,'2018Q4'
 ,'2019Q1'
 ,'2019Q2']

 data=[146660510.0
 ,123641451.0
 ,125905843.0
 ,129656327.0
 ,126586708.0
 ,116804168.0
 ,118167263.0
 ,121633740.0
 ,125314447.0
 ,120994896.0
 ,126124709.0
 ,134753318.0]

 df=pd.DataFrame({'date':date,'data':data})
 df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
 df=df.set_index('date')
 ax=df.plot(figsize=(14,2))
 plt.show()

 decomposition=sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(x=df['data'],model='additive',      extrapolate_trend='freq', period=3)

 decomposition_trend=decomposition.trend
 ax= decomposition_trend.plot(figsize=(14,2))
 ax.set_xlabel('Date')
 ax.set_ylabel('Trend of time series')
 ax.set_title('Trend values of the time series')
 plt.show()

 decomposition_residual=decomposition.resid
 ax= decomposition_residual.plot(figsize=(14,2))
 ax.set_xlabel('Date')
 ax.set_ylabel('Residual of time series')
 ax.set_title('Residual values of the time series')
 plt.show()
```

Comment: This example helped me but I don't understand one part. I have monthly data and I was setting the period to 12 and receive the error. After seeing your example I set the period to 11 and it works just fine. How is the period set? Is it always points in a year minus 1?

Comment: documentation: Period of the series. Must be used if x is not a pandas object or if the index of x does not have a frequency. Overrides default periodicity of x if x is a pandas object with a timeseries index.

Comment: In my example I am intrepolating 3 data points at a time for the frequency.